# How to select the state from within Redux-Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, token, redux-saga

I have a react app where I'm creating an unit and it requires authorization.

```
function* createUnitWorker(action) {
  const { payload: {unitDetails, history} } = action;
  try {
    const unit = yield axios({
      method: 'post',     
      url: `https://myBackend/units/`,
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer'+token}, 
      data: {
         ...unitDetails
      }
    });
    yield put(call(createUnitSuccess, unit));
    yield history.push(`/unit/${unit.code}`)
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(createUnitFailure(error));
    yield put(history.push('/error'))
  }
}
export function* createUnitWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest(unitActionTypes.CREATE_UNIT_START, createUnitWorker);
}
```

Should I send the token from the component as part of the payload or should I select the token from the user state I have stored in the saga?. Because it seems to me that it is complicated to select the token mapStateToProps and then send it with the action when I could just select the token from within the saga

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use axios [interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) so you don't have to manually add the token to each request you send.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://baseUrl.com',
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer'+token;
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

This means you can just use the axiosInstance in each saga, without worrying about the token. Something like this:

```
axiosInstance.post('/units', payload);
```